# Connecting batteries in parallel to the existing batteries that are connected in series

Tags: batteries, parallel, series

I have 6 12V batteries all the same volt and same amp. I need 48V to use and I connected 4 batteries in series to get the 48V, but two extra batteries are just laying there doing nothing. I thought of adding them also to the system to use without increasing the volt. See the image on how they are connected.
[image]

If I connect the batteries as explained in the drawing would work?

Comment: Just connect 4 batteries in series and leave the other two. There's no way you can use them without creating an unbalanced stack.

Answer (score 4):

I've decyphered and redrawn your, well, let's call it a graphical intimation, as a schematic, to make it clearer why this won't work

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8BsgW.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

Now it's obvious that F's connections are short-circuiting C and D, and E's connections are short-circuiting A and B.

If you merely disconnect the shorting connections as another answer has suggested, then you'll end up with two high capacity batteries in series with two low capacity batteries. **Do Not Do This** The capacity of the string will be no more than the single batteries in series. If you monitor the total voltage on the string for endpoint, you'll overdischarge the single cells, and the whole series string will be impossible to charge properly.

We assume that the series batteries are of the same capacity, type and age, in order to properly monitor, charge and balance them. If they are not, do not connect them in series.

The best way to use your two extra batteries would be to sell them, and use the money for something else.

Another way, if they are fairly new, would be to buy two extra batteries so you have two, 48 V strings. If the batteries have any appreciable service, do not do this, as connecting batteries of different age in series runs into the same monitoring/charging/balancing problems as batteries of different capacity in series.

Another way is to cycle them in and out of your service string of 4, so that wear and tear on them will be reduced. This needs regular changing and attention to routine, so may be difficult. There's wear and tear on the connections as well.

Another way to use your two extra batteries is to connect them to a 24 to 48 V boost converter, and use them instead of the series 4 for part of the load cycle, or in parallel with them if your boost converter can tolerate that. If your booster is current output, like a LED driver for instance, then it can easily be paralleled with the 48 V string, when the total load current is above the output current of the booster.

Yet another way is to configure them into two 36 V strings, or a single 72 V string, and use a DC-DC converter to bring them to your desired 48 V output. You gain voltage stability and flexibility with this method, which might be beneficial.

Answer (score 3):

Bad idea and terrible implementation. If these are lead-acid batteries then there is severe risk of personal injury.

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2f8M4if.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

*Figure 1a: OP's circuit redrawn. 1b: Correct wiring.*

- The blue wire is short-circuiting the 24 V of A + B.
- The green wire is short-circuiting the 24 V of B + C (and E).
- The orange is shorting out the 24 V of B + C.
- The combination of red and blue is shorting out the 48 V of A + B + C + D.

For series connected batteries they should all be the same size and capacity.

Use four. Add a fuse.

Answer (score -3):

The way you have made the battery connection will end up confusing yourself and you will create a mess. We already have some answers but I would ask you to go for a simple approach and then go for a compact design If you are looking to reduce space or so.

This simpler approach should help you out:
[image: Circuit]

Another thing, I'm new to this site so please spare me for this image I'm not known how to add those circuit simulations directly

Comment: Putting sets of cells with different total capacity in series like this is a bad idea.  There is no way to charge such an arrangement properly, and no way to safely discharge its full capacity.  As far as the diagram, When you're authoring a question, one of the buttons at the top will bring up a schematic editor and it's rather easy to find most components in it, although hand drawings aren't completely forbidden.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I agree on your point.

Comment: PS Welcome to EE.SE =)

Comment: Thanks for your welcoming gesture ! @KH

Comment: While I echo KH's welcome, I would say very strongly do not post answers that will damage the OP's equipment without at least mentioning that fact in your answer. Series connection of unequal capacity risks over-discharge on the single cells if voltage monitoring is done on the whole string. The schematic editor button is right there on the editor toolbar, though it's easy to miss. It's next to the image add button.

Comment: @Neil_UK I'm sorry I didn't have intension to damage the questioner's equipment. Infact this field is very new to me and what I had learnt until now I thought would help the questioner. If this post is very much harmful then please tell I won't post any answers without any detailed knowledge about that and please consider to flag this question or ping me to delete it or down vote such that others should not repeat mistake made by me and simply ignore my answer.

Comment: I knew that having different sizes of batteries in series wouldn't work at a full capacity. Whatever the size of the smallest battery, that would be then your capacity. I am also new into the electric works. Don't worry about the drawing. As long as the reader can understand it. Welcome!

Comment: @JenilDave Your drawing is fine, it's completely legible. However, please add some text to your answer saying something along the lines of 'don't do this because ...' if you are going to leave it up.

Comment: @Neil_UK Thanks and I will make sure that I add advantages and disadvantages in future posts. Thanks for your guidance EE.SE Community!